# PHP require does not work without any error

Tags: php, require

I have the following code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
print("file_exist(): ".file_exists("/home/path/to/file/file.php"));
$reqRes = require("/home/path/to/file/file.php");
print("after require $reqRes");
```

the output is like this

```
file_exist(): 1
```

I do not understand what is happening. File exists, next line after required is not called and no errors. I put inside file.php the first line like this
print("print from file.php");

and still no changes. I only get `file_exist(): 1` as output.

How can I debug this problem and understand what is happening?

Comment: What's in `file.php`? Maybe it's calling `exit()`

Comment: Wasn't echo the `print` function in PHP?

Comment: @LuisCárcamo print and echo work the same in this case

Comment: As far as I can tell you should be getting an error, or the print statement should work. I am curious as to what the code in /home/path/to/file/file.php looks like

Comment: I found the problem, file.php was copied automatically by parent script from some other location to /home/path/to/file/file.php, so any changes were overwritten. when I put print in the original location, then print started working. no magic.